# Get list items from a site collection in different Geo location using REST API in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, multi-geo

I'm trying to get list items from a different Geo-location within the same tenant in an SPFx solution. I've tried pnp-js, spHttpClient, etc and end up getting 403. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: We are facing a similar behavior. Did you find a solution? Would be much appreciated

Comment: @mJay Unfortunately no. This is by design from MS. Each geo location goes through it's own authentication and you'll 403 as long as the user isn't authenticated to the other geo. You might have to do something like a pre-authentication.

Comment: @mJay Did you find a solution?